# Cambiar color a enlace de menú pulsado

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy buscando información sobre cómo cambiar el color a un enlace de menú en el cual he entrado, es decir, pulso en el enlace, me redirige a la dirección y ese enlace en el menú se muestra de otro color, para que el usuario sepa donde se encuentra. He intentado buscar soluciones sólo con CSS pero no he llegado a ningún sitio, ¿sabéis si es necesario el uso de javascript para realizar esto?

Gracias!

Comment: Buenas, revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Tienes literalmente miles de tutoriales y ejemplos sobre menus css. [Aqui](https://codepen.io/Patak/pen/QpLpOV) solo un ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La opción idonea (desde mi punto de vista) es que lo hagas con js. Realmente lo que haces es que cuando se hace un "click" el boton cambie y se quede cambiado.

Lo suyo es que tengas una clase:

```
.active{
    bacground-color:green;
}
```

Que tenga por defecto tu botón de home. Y que cuando tengas un click, en cualquier elemento del menu, busque quién tenia el active, se lo quite, y se lo ponga al nuevo.

```
object.onclick = function(){myScript};
```

[Más info onClick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

De este modo evitas meter "styles" directamente desde js, que se mete inline:

```
<button ... style="...">
```

Por limpieza, claridad y mantenimiento, luego si quieres cambiar el efecto del elemento elegido, solo tienes que cambiar esta clase.

Espero haber podido ayudar y lo siento si me he ido un poco por las ramas. 
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, si sólo quieres utilizar HTML/CSS te pongo una opción un poco cutre, pero no conozco ninguna otra que deje marcado el link en el que te encuentras sin usar javascript y teniendo en cuenta que no usas vistas modulares a través de AJAX y sin usar un lenguaje de lado del servidor.

Sólo utilizando HTML y CSS:

Le pones al body una clase:

```
<body class=”home”>
```

A continuación te creas tu menú:

```
<ul>

<li><a href="home.html" class="home">Home</a>

<li><a href="pagina1.html" class="pg1">Página 1</a>

<li><a href="pagina2.html" class="pag2">Página 2</a>

</ul>
```

Ahora creas el CSS y le dices que coja la clase del body y dependiendo de qué clase tenga le pondrá el color, como cada página de body tiene una única clase que no se repite, se marcará en color la página en la que estés:

```
body.home a.home, body.pg1 a.pg1, body.pg2 a.pg2 {

background-color: blue;

}
```

Entiendo que estarás utilizando esto para un sitio pequeño, ya que esta opción es difícil de mantener. Cuando indagues más verás que lo correcto sería utilizar JS (desde mi punto de vista).

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, aunque yo sinceramente lo haría con JavaScript.